# Putting a model on every view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to pass my UserModel to every view, so it can show on top the current user information.

This is my **BaseViewModel**:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public UserModel currentUser { get; set; }
}
```

**BaseController:**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        UserRepository userRep = new UserRepository();
        BaseViewModel model = new BaseViewModel
        {
            currentUser = userRep.getCurrentUser()
        };
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**HomeController:** (default)

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ListRepository listRep = new ListRepository();
        return View(listRep.GetAllLists());//returns IEnumerable<ListModel>
    }
}
```

My shared **_layout.cshtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Public/css")
</head>
<body>
        <header>
            @Html.Partial("_Header")
        </header>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

and finally, my **_Header.cshtml:**

```
<div id="logo">
    <h1>Hello @Model.currentUser.username</ h1 >
</div>
```

But I get this error message when I run it:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'currentUser'

I thought my `BaseViewModel` would always get appended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model in the view is `IEnumerable<ListModel>` and that is what will be passed to the partial unless you specify a model, for example, using

```
@Html.Partial("_Header", someOtherModel)
```

Instead, create a `ChildActionOnly` method that returns your user data to the `_Header.cshtml` partial view and in the main view use `@Html.Action()` to render it

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _Header()
{
   var model = .... // get the model you want to render in the partial
   return PartialView(model);
}
```

and in the main view

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("_Header", controllerName); }
```

Comment: Should I create a new controller or add it to an existing one? Also, unrelated, is it possible to return a different partial view depending if the user is logged in or not?

Comment: Personally I would have it in a separate controller (maybe `UserController`) assuming you will be using that partial in multiple views associated with multiple controllers

Comment: And you can always check if the request is authenticated, and use `return PartialView("abc", model);` or `return PartialView("xyz", model);` (and even the models could be different)

Comment: Thank you very much,  I was stuck on this for quite some time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that in every view, you may consider calling a child action method using Html.Action.

So replace

```
<header>@Html.Partial("_Header")</header>
```

with

```
<header>@Html.Action("Header","YourControllerName")</header>
```

Now have an action method called Header where you will pass the needed data to it's partial view

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Header()
{
  var vm = new YourHeaderViewModel();
  vm.UserName="Shyju"; // Replace with whatever you want.
  return PartialView(vm);
}
```

Where YourHeaderViewModel is your view mode for the header with the properties needed for the header.

```
public class YourHeaderViewModel
{
  public string UserName {set;get;}
}
```

Now in your Header partial view which is strongly typed to the YourHeaderViewModel class,

```
@model YourHeaderViewModel
<div id="logo">
    <h1>Hello @Model.UserName</ h1 >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using BaseController.

Instantiate your BaseViewModel model in OnResultExecuting method instead of OnActionExecuted. And save the model in ViewData to access it in _Header partial view.

E.g.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
        UserRepository userRep = new UserRepository();
        BaseViewModel model = new BaseViewModel
        {
            currentUser = userRep.getCurrentUser()
        };
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["customData"] = model;
        }
    }
```

Now you need to pass ViewData to _Header partial view.

E.g.

```
@Html.Partial("_Header", ViewData["customData"])
```

In _Header partial view, you can simply access the data.

```
<div id="logo">
    <h1>Hello @Model.currentUser.username</ h1 >
</div>
```